# Showing tool tip for every item in datagridview row when mouse is above it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

How can you show the tooltip for `datagridview` for every item in `datagridview` when you hover mouse over the item in that particular row?

I have table `product` with columns:

```
product name 
product price 
product description
product image ....
```

I have a requirement that I have a `datagridview` with columns and I am getting these from  database:

```
product name 
product price 
product image ....
```

Now I want to show the tooltip like this: if I have mouse over the product image, the product description will be displayed for that product. I want to do this for every row. Would anyone please help on this one?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Take a look at the [DataGridViewCell.ToolTipText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tooltiptext.aspx) and use the DataGridView's `CellFormatting` event to set this property value.  You can use the event's `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` `ColumnIndex` property to determine if the event is firing for the column you want to set a tool tip for and if so use the event's `RowIndex` to specify that tool tip's value.

The sample in the MSDN article I linked have a fine example of usage, but your code might look something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns[nameOrIndexOfYourImageColumn].Index) {
        var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        // Set the Cell's ToolTipText.  In this case we're retrieving the value stored in 
        // another cell in the same row (see my note below).
        cell.ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[nameOrIndexOfYourDescriptionColumn].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Where:
 `nameOrIndexOfYourImageColumn` = the column name or index value of your image column
 `nameOrIndexOfYourDescriptionColumn` = the column name or index value with your description data.

Note: that you'll need some way to retrieve a row's Description data. A common way to do this is to have a column for it in your DataGridView, but make since you don't want to display this column set its `Visible` property to false.  There are other options however.

Comment: `cell.ToolTipText` is really ugly, though. It positions the tooltip not below your mouse where you would expect a tooltip, but at the point where your mouse entered the cell.

Answer (score 7):

I have done this by storing the text to show in the tooltip for each cell in the `Tag` property of each `DataGridViewCell`.

Then in the `DataGridView.CellMouseEnter` event you can see in which cell the mouse is using the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs.ColumnIndex` and `DataGridViewCellEventArgs.RowIndex` values and set the text from the corresponding cell as the tooltip text using `ToolTip.SetToolTip`.

If works pretty well.

Something like this:

```
private void dgv_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 & e.RowIndex >= 0) 
    {
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(dgv, Convert.ToString(dgv.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Tag));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When filling the `datagridview`, just set the `TooltipText` property of the cell to the text you want to display.