# ToolTip of DataGridCell occurs value disappearing

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid

I have problem with ToolTip in my DataGridCell style. When I try to show content of cell in tooltip this content disappears. I must show this tooltip on each cell and I generate columns dinamically so I can't bind to any property name. Here is my snippet:

```
<Style x:Key="dgCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=FocusBorderBrushKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Controls:DataGrid}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Does anyone have any idea? 
Thanks

Comment: You better check [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173430/showing-tool-tip-for-every-item-in-datagridview-row-when-mouse-is-above-it

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the link you have posted is about winforms and i need solution with wpf framework and not by code behind but in xaml way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add **tooltip** to `DataGridTextColumn`,

you could use `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle property`,

Refer to below code snippet:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ScreenName" Binding="{Binding Name}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Age}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Or you can go through this [Link](http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/Silverlight/Add-Tooltip-to-DataGrid-Column-Header.aspx)

**Update :-**

if you're generating columns dynamically you can handle `MouseMove` event on the grid.

You can then transform coordinates of the mouse to the row handle and change grid's tooltip accordingly.

`Something like`:

```
private void dataGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
 var point = dataGrid.PointToClient(e.X, e.Y);
 var hittest = dataGrid.HitTest(point.X, point.Y);
 toolTip1.SetToolTip(dataGrid, hittest.Row); // **add Tooltip control to the Application!!!**
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this way of adding tooltip because i generate columns dinamically, as i wrote in main post, So I can't bind tooltip's text with concrete property. I must use binding to cell's content

Comment: Check the updated answer you have to add a tooltip control to the application .

Comment: This what you've posted is for winforms datagrid. I've found way to do this with MouseMove event, but I don't want to do this. In this project I'm using MVVM pattern so I try to avoid codebehind in view file. I wonder why this what i've posted on the start doesn't work because it's one way binding so this shouldn't be problem with show this tooltip. I want to do this only with XAML because it should work but I don't know why it doesn't :) I hope that some person with very good knowledge of XAML can help me with this :)